# Use ESRI Web Adaptor to restrict Rest Services breadcrumbs

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-web-adaptor

Am I able to restrict users from following the breadcrumb path on my rest services back to the source and seeing every rest service offered on my server?

We are using the Web Adaptor on a 10.1 ESRI server.

Comment: You can close access to Service Directory in 10.1+ http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/admin.html. If this is not what you are looking for, can you specify in details how exactly do you want to limit user access to the Services Directory and what type of information? Maybe a couple of small screenshots?